# Gmail not working with PHP integrated mail() for outgoing mails

Tags: php, dns, gmail, phpmailer

We are having some major problems with the new gmail updates.
Most of our page doesn't send mails anymore since our MX DNS is linked to Gmail. Now most of our functions that use PHP mail() does ONLY send e-mail every second mail.
How come? Anyone experiencing the same issue?

Again, I can confirm that it works for every second mail I send, to certain emails. Not all.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that particular issue, but in general, most devs would recommend SwiftMailer, PHPMailer or another application like that instead of the default `mail()` function. Have you tried that?

Comment: I know, but I've heard that this has affected quite a lot of forms created as widgets etc. in Joomla and Wordpress... Weird that Google would update their system to prevent the standard PHP from working...

Comment: I'm guessing it's a measure against spam. Google *hates* spam.

Comment: Still, disabling one of the most common mail functions in PHP is pretty radical...

Comment: As I said, I don't really have any knowledge about this, but Google set very strict standards about mails coming from `mail()`, the headers have to be near perfect as far as I understand.

Comment: It's not for receiving, its for sending from gmail... Our DNS i set so that all outgoing emails are sent using `mail()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if your mailer supports tls and if you are using SMTPSecure. Both are required by google to minimize spam.

I highly recommend you using a mailer class such as [PHP Mailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

A tutorial for gmail using PHP Mailer : https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps

Comment: Why is it all of the sudden required? It has worked all the time until about 4-5 days ago, what is the new update?

Comment: I have no idea. GMail is doing weekly updates fixing problems and exploits non stop. I dont know exactly but maybe they have some new security system or something.